# A homeomorphism of open sets of Euclidean spaces

Tags: general-topology

Given non-empty open subsets $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $V\subset \mathbb{R}^m$ with $n\neq m$, is there a homeomorphism $f:U  \to V $ in the topological sense ? .

Comment: Consider non empty open subsets $U$ and $V$.

Comment: $U=(0,1)$ is connected but $V=(0,1) \cup (1,2)$ isn't...

Comment: But $(0,1)$ and $(0,1)\cup (1,2)$ still open subsets of the same Euclidean space, namely $\mathbb{R}$. Please read the question once more @user251257

Comment: you haven't stated $m\ne n$. You should ask question more carefully.

Comment: My apologizes. I edited the question.

Comment: Can you adapt the connectedness argument for higher dimensions?

Comment: Do you mean *homeomorphism*?

Comment: Yes, a bijective continuous function whose inverse is continuous as well. @NoahSchweber

Comment: Dimension is a topological invariant so no. I'll let someone else give the proof.

Comment: Could you clarify more please ? or state the theorem or the proposition. @MarkJoshi

Comment: [Homeomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism) and [homomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphism) are different concepts.

Comment: http://math.ucr.edu/~res/miscpapers/top-dimension-theory.pdf

Comment: It's easy to think about an counter-example.

Comment: This is often dubbed "invariance of domain" in the literature.

Comment: With m\ne n even if you assume the sets are connected, simply-connected and not empty the answer is No. The case m=1 is easy. The case 1<m<n, not easy, I think.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain

Comment: If this were true would you have a homeomorphism from some open n-balll to some open m-ball?

Answer (score 1):

Just take, for example, $U=(0,1)\subset\Bbb{R}$ and $V=B_1({\bf 0})=\{x\in\Bbb{R}:\|x\|<1\}\subset\Bbb{R}^2$ and note that $U$ and $V$ aren't homeomorphic by an argument of connectedness.

**Edit:** Suppose there exist a homeomorphism $f:V\to U$, let $v\in V$ and $u=f(v)\in U$. Then, $V\setminus\{v\}$ is connected and, since $f$ is continuous, we have that $f(V\setminus\{v\})=U\setminus\{u\}$ is connected, a contradiction. So, $U$ and $V$ can't be homeomorphic.

Comment: Ok, I edited it.

Comment: looks good ${}{}$

Answer (score 1):

Assume they are homeomorphic. Then some ball within each are homeomorphic. But these balls are homeomorphic to their ambient spaces so then R^n is homeomorphic to R^m, n

Answer (score 1):

The approach rdias refers to, by removing a point of the set to check for connectedness, is actually very related to how you can prove a more general result in algebraic topology. The construction is quite technical and requires homology groups, exicsion, the Mayer-Vietoris-sequence and other tools you encounter in algebraic topology, but let me hand-wave the geist of it.

To start of you can show that the unit spheres dimension $k$ and $m$ have isomorphic $n$th homology groups $H_n(S^k)\cong H_n(S^m)$ if and only if $k=m$ for $n>0$. What this means is that the spheres have a "hole" of the same dimension only if they are of the same dimension, which is intuitively obvious, but quite hard to show.

If you accept that, however, the proof is rather simple: the real space $\mathbb R^n\smallsetminus 0$ with the zero removed also has a hole in the middle, so it is a "thick" sphere. In technical terms it is homotopy equivalent to the sphere $S^{n-1}$. By this, one can show that if $\mathbb R^k\cong \mathbb R^m$, then $H_n(S^{k-1})\cong H_n(S^{m-1})$ which happens only if $k=m$.

Since any open ball of either space is homeomorphic to the entire space, your answer pops out easily by this reasoning.

---

Want a reference? Well, try any book on algebraic topology, like A. Hatchers book which is free online if I recall correctly.